# Is it possible to use mutex to lock only one element of a data structure ?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking, mutex

Is it possible to use mutex  to lock only one element of a data structure ? 
e.g.

```
boost::mutex m_mutex;
map<string, int> myMap;
// initialize myMap so that it has 10 elements

// then in thread 1
{
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
myMap[1] = 5 ; // write map[1]
}
// in thread 2
{ 
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    myMap[2] = 4 ; // write map[1]
}
```

My question: 
When thread 1 is writing  map[1], thread 2 can writing map[2] at the same time ? 
The thread lock the whole map data structure or only an element, e.g. map[1] or map[2].

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you can guarantee that nobody is modifying the container itself (via `insert` and `erase` etc.), then as long as each thread accesses a **different element** of the container, you should be fine.

If you need per-element locking, you could modify the element type to something that offers synchronized access. (Worst case a pair of a mutex and the original value.)

Answer (score 3):

You need a different mutex for every element of the map. You can do this with a map of mutex or adding a mutex to the mapped type (in your case it is int, so you can't do it without creating a new class like SharedInt)

Answer (score 0):

Mutex is all about discipline. One thread can call write and other thread can call write1. C++ runtime will assume it is intentional. But most of the cases it is not the programmer intended. Summary is as long as all threads/methods follow the discipline (understand the the critical section and respect it) there will be consistency.

```
int i=0;

Write()
{
    //Lock 
    i++;
    //Unlock
}

Write1()
{
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes lock executable regions not objects. I always think about locking any code regions that read/modify thread objects. If an object is locked within a region but that object is accessible within another un-synchronized code region, you are not safe (ofcourse). In your case, I'd lock access to the entire object as insertions and reading from containers can easily experience context switching and thus increase the likelihood of data corruption.

Comment: "_Mutexes lock executable regions not objects_" no, locks lock mutexes. What is an "executable region"?